# append elements from another html page using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to append or manipulate elements from another html page ?

I have used this but didnt work

```
$.ajax({
            method:"get",
            url:"html2.html",
        })
        .success(function(response)
        {
            $("body").append("<p> example  </p>")
        });
```

if it is possible how can i do that  with  jquery.

I have searched for that but I could not  find something

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "from another page"?

Comment: my mean is  append from main html page to the external html page

Comment: add more details about what you have tried, or the question might be closed.

Comment: If you are trying to write **to** another page, as in modify an arbitrary external HTML page that you don't control, that is not possible.

Comment: I guess ,for instance,  you would like to append news text from "Admin.html" to "News.html" dynamically . please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP GET to get the content of a website, then find the desired element you want to append and append it to where you want.

You can use ajax to get the page's content like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://www.urlyouwanttoget.com",
})
.success(function( response ) {
   // Code here 
});
```

In this case the `reponse` parameter will have all html content of the website. Inside the success method you can use `.find()` method to find the element you want to append and finally use `$('#yourcontainer').append(contentToAppend)` to append the content in your desired container.

NOTE: You may get the Cross-Origin Request Bloqued alert in the console that won't let you read remote's content, you can solve that looking around in Stack Overflow, it is a very common scenario and it is easy to solve.